# If sentence on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

This code comes from the controller(`class MainController < ApplicationController`) On console i can view the content from `puts wallMessage.messagedestiny` and `puts current_user.id` but on the next lines don't shows anything inside the sentence where the values are the same, here come the code:

```
Message.each do |wallMessage|
        puts wallMessage.messagedestiny
        puts current_user.id
        if wallMessage.messagedestiny == current_user.id # <-- from here don't show anything from the following content in the sentence
          puts "*** entra en el each y devuelve el wallMessage"
          puts wallMessage
          @wallMessages.push(wallMessage.messagecontent)
          User.find_by(id: wallMessage.messagesender) do |messageSender|
            @messageSenders.push(messageSender.username)
          end
        end
      end
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? Its totally unclear as to what you're asking.

Comment: edited, more clear?

Comment: What was the output of `wallMessage.messagedestiny` and `current_user.id`?

Comment: `57a4df6927d8754bd68aaade
57a4df6927d8754bd68aaade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `if` statement didn't get executed, its clear that the `type` of the values don't match.

Try this and you can check if for yourself.

```
puts wallMessage.message‌​destiny.class # displays the type of object
puts current_user.id.class
```

or

```
puts wallMessage.message‌​destiny.class == current_user.id.class
```

You can convert the `type` of one of the values to the other and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

```
if wallMessage.messagedestiny == String(current_user.id) # <-- Solution is convert to String cause current_user.id.class on console returned a BSON object
          puts "*** entra en el each y devuelve el wallMessage"
          puts wallMessage
          @wallMessages.push(wallMessage.messagecontent)
          User.find_by(id: wallMessage.messagesender) do |messageSender|
            @messageSenders.push(messageSender.username)
          end
        end
```

Comment: You could also use `current_user.id.to_s` to convert the integer to a string.
Less keystrokes.